# How to hide edge labels in Sigma.js

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I'm using the sigma.renderers.edgeLabels plugin.
I want to change the color of the labels when i change the color of the edge. My question is, is possible to access these labels in a way like this?:

```
s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
          e.originalColor = e.color;
    });
```